# Regular Expression to find a group of strings between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have:

```
[Radius: 4000 mi.] -- 61362 -- Spring Valley, IL, US
```

The aim is to get:

```
Spring Valley, IL
```

I want to achieve this with RegEx. When I try `(?<=--)(.*?)(?=\, US)` I can't seem to get the second group of '--' out.

Comment: Just use `(str.match(/.*--\s*(.*?),\s*US/) || ['', ''])[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lookbehind, but in between you should not match `--` again

```
(?<= -- )(?:(?! --).)*(?=, US)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdX9az/1)

```js
const s = `[Radius: 4000 mi.] -- 61362 -- Spring Valley, IL, US`;
const regex = /(?<= -- )(?:(?! --).)*(?=, US)/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[0]);
```

You can also use a capture group and make the match as specific as you want:

```
--\s+\d+\s+--\s+(.*?), US\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n02U7M/1)

```js
const s = `[Radius: 4000 mi.] -- 61362 -- Spring Valley, IL, US`;
const regex = /--\s+\d+\s+--\s+(.*?), US\b/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to considering a non-regex approach, you can split the string on the hyphens and spaces (' -- '), take the element at index 2 (the city, state, country), split that by the comma limiting the results to 2, and then rejoining by a comma, and you have what you're looking for.

Easier to read than a regex approach, and likely easier for other developers in your code base to understand what is happening.

```js
const s = '[Radius: 4000 mi.] -- 61362 -- Spring Valley, IL, US';

const cityState = s.split(' -- ')[2]?.split(',', 2).join(',');

console.log(cityState);
```